# Select a row when a column changed

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that stores when an object changes and when it was marked.

```
id  name   markedAt    updatedAt
1   X      2019-01-01  2019-01-01
2   x2     2019-01-01  2019-01-02
3   x2     null        2019-01-03
4   x2     2019-01-04  2019-01-04
5   x3     2019-01-04  2019-01-05
```

```
#1 - the object was marked and updated
#2 - the object was updated
#3 - was unmarked
#4 - was marked again
#5 - was updated
```

How do I write a query that retrieves the row when the object was marked for the last time. In this case, I want the row #4.

Comment: Either MySQL or SQL, please clarify?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: MySQL, sorry. Thought SQL tag was about SQL in general not SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use a subquery for max marketAt  in join

```
    select m.* from  my_table m
    inner join  (
    select name, max(markedAt) max_mark
    from my_table
    group by name 
    ) t on t.markedAt = m.markedAt and t.name = m.name
```

this shoud return  value for each name  .. 
if you need  just name = x2  add the proper where

```
    select m.* from  my_table m
    inner join  (
    select name, max(markedAt) max_mark
    from my_table
    group by name 
    ) t on t.markedAt = m.markedAt and t.name = m.name 
    where name  = 'x2'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need first to get the maximum date `where markedat = updatedat` for each object with group by and then join to the main table:

```
select t.* 
from  tablename t
inner join  (
  select 
    name, 
    max(markedat) maxmarkedat
  from tablename 
  where 
    markedat = updatedat
  group by name 
) g 
on g.maxmarkedat = t.updatedat and g.maxmarkedat = t.markedAt and g.name = t.name
```